# "tar (child): Cannot connect to https: resolve failed" when installing Bitmask

Tags: software-installation, tar

I am trying to install Bitmask on my system to get the riseup VPN running(https://help.riseup.net/en/vpn/how-to/linux), but as you can see, there are no packages for Fedora.

I tried the compressed files you get by using curl as well as the direct download from the Bitmask site, but both give me this output while unpacking:

```
tar xfj https://dl.bitmask.net/client/GNU/Linux/Bitmask-GNU/Linux64-latest.tar.bz2
tar (child): Cannot connect to https: resolve failed

bzip2: Compressed file ends unexpectedly;
    perhaps it is corrupted?  *Possible* reason follows.
bzip2: Inappropriate ioctl for device
    Input file = (stdin), output file = (stdout)

It is possible that the compressed file(s) have become corrupted.
You can use the -tvv option to test integrity of such files.

You can use the `bzip2recover' program to attempt to recover
data from undamaged sections of corrupted files.

tar: Child returned status 128
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the guide is boggus. `tar xfj https://dl.bitmask.net/client/GNU/Linux/Bitmask-GNU/Linux64-latest.tar.bz2` will never work. You see that the 32-bit instructions are *somewhat* correct as they don't use a scheme. Second, that file doesn't even exist in the server:

```
➜  ~  wget https://dl.bitmask.net/client/GNU/Linux/Bitmask-GNU/Linux64-latest.tar.bz2   
--2014-09-07 12:27:41--  https://dl.bitmask.net/client/GNU/Linux/Bitmask-GNU/Linux64-latest.tar.bz2
Resolving dl.bitmask.net (dl.bitmask.net)... 176.53.69.114
Connecting to dl.bitmask.net (dl.bitmask.net)|176.53.69.114|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2014-09-07 12:27:42 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

That's why tar fail. You should use this instead:

```
curl -O https://dl.bitmask.net/client/linux/Bitmask-linux64-latest.tar.bz2
curl -O https://dl.bitmask.net/client/linux/Bitmask-linux64-latest.tar.bz2.asc
gpg --verify Bitmask-linux64-latest.tar.bz2.asc Bitmask-linux64-latest.tar.bz2
```

After that, I presume you know what comes.

Comment: I unpacked it, but when I try to install it by `./config` it says that there is no such file or directory.

Comment: @Merlin "After that, I presume you know what comes." I don't know what comes next. Follow the guide you are doing.

Comment: Sorry. The guide stops right after unpacking the archive and the Readme says nothing about installing but to look in docs/user/install.rst and I have no idea where that's supposed to be.

Comment: @Merlin there's no need to "install" it, just run `./bitmask`.

Comment: Well, that at least made a new problem come up(see edit).

Comment: @Merlin you should ask a new question instead.